# Using public variables and interfaces in external libraries when using Typescript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript, angular

I am fairly new to Typescript and am developing an Angular 2.0/Typescript application. I have made d3 available as a typing and I would like to use public methods from D3 as well as interfaces.

To make d3 available I have added the following code:

`declare var d3`

I need to use the following interface:

`private _axises: D3.Selection`

and the following public method.

`this._axises = d3.select(...)`

How do I make both "d3" and "D3" available for usage without the Typescript transpiler throwing any errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make both "d3" and "D3" available for usage without the Typescript transpiler throwing any errors?

You seem to want to use *community* written d3 defintions. In that case you should not add *your* own i.e. don't have `declare var d3` anywhere in your code. This should come with `d3.d.ts` available here : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/d3

## More

You can install it using typings `typings install d3 --ambient --save`. Also if you are using a module system use `import * as d3 from "d3"` e.g. in [alm.tools](http://alm.tools/) I have https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/894a6f095ecc84c8e32adf79c1bb7d595eba877d/src/app/tabs/dependencyView.tsx#L8

Comment: Thanks basarat, in your example you have the import statement for d3. When I do that, I get a "Cannot find module" error unless I use "/// <reference path="...". Is this good practice? How does your Typescript transpiler recognise Typings without the reference?

Comment: Using tsconfig.json : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/compilation-context.html