# Typescript throws error with Array.find

Tags: typescript, angular, ecmascript-6

I've just completed the Angular 2.0 Tour of Heroes tutorial and I've added the following Gulp file (simplified for this example) to build it:

```
var del = require('del');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('transpile-ts', function() {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(paths.allTypeScript)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest_js));
});
```

I want to add an Array.find method into dashboard.component.ts as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let newVar: Array<number> = new Array();
    newVar.push(0);
    newVar.push(1);
    newVar.find(d => d == 1);

    this._heroService.getHeroes()
        .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1,5));
}
```

When I run the command "gulp transpile-ts" however I get the following error:

***app\dashboard.component.ts(26,16): error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist
on type 'number[]'.***

I have es6-shim.d.ts included so the "find" method does exist under "interface Array".

Also I tried running the same task with Grunt and the same issue occurred so it's not a Gulp issue.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation I noticed that when using 'tsc' in the CMD line to transpile the Typsecript everything worked as expected. Instead of using 'gulp.src' in my gulp file I should have used 'tsProject.src' to emulate this.

This was answered here https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/issues/313.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!

Answer (score 5):

> I have es6-shim.d.ts included so the "find" method does exist under "interface Array".

Apparently that shim doesn't add the `find` method to Array. You should have:

```
interface Array<T> {
    /** 
      * Returns the value of the first element in the array where predicate is true, and undefined 
      * otherwise.
      * @param predicate find calls predicate once for each element of the array, in ascending 
      * order, until it finds one where predicate returns true. If such an element is found, find 
      * immediately returns that element value. Otherwise, find returns undefined.
      * @param thisArg If provided, it will be used as the this value for each invocation of 
      * predicate. If it is not provided, undefined is used instead.
      */
    find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: Array<T>) => boolean, thisArg?: any): T;
}
```

## Update

Even multiple declarations shouldn't cause an error. The following compiles just fine:

```
interface Array<T> {
    /** 
      * Returns the value of the first element in the array where predicate is true, and undefined 
      * otherwise.
      * @param predicate find calls predicate once for each element of the array, in ascending 
      * order, until it finds one where predicate returns true. If such an element is found, find 
      * immediately returns that element value. Otherwise, find returns undefined.
      * @param thisArg If provided, it will be used as the this value for each invocation of 
      * predicate. If it is not provided, undefined is used instead.
      */
    find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: Array<T>) => boolean, thisArg?: any): T;    

}
interface Array<T> {
    /** 
      * Returns the value of the first element in the array where predicate is true, and undefined 
      * otherwise.
      * @param predicate find calls predicate once for each element of the array, in ascending 
      * order, until it finds one where predicate returns true. If such an element is found, find 
      * immediately returns that element value. Otherwise, find returns undefined.
      * @param thisArg If provided, it will be used as the this value for each invocation of 
      * predicate. If it is not provided, undefined is used instead.
      */
    find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: Array<T>) => boolean, thisArg?: any): T;    
}

var foo:any[]
foo.find((x)=>true);
```

So check the contents of es6-shim.d.ts to make sure it confirms.

Comment: Thanks for your response basarat. I do have that code in the es6-shim file and I can even navigate to it. I do have multiple choices when I "Choose Declaration" on the "find" property with files such as "global.d.ts" not sure if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Mutilple decarations should not cause an error. See update.

Comment: I found the issue is with "gulp-typescript". When I use just tsc this error disappears. Using just tsc solves this error too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001159/using-public-variables-and-interfaces-in-external-libraries-when-using-typescrip/36002069#36002069. Do you have any experience with "gulp-typescript"? Thanks

Comment: find type should return `T | undefined`